# clean before every build (package)

Tags: maven, ant, build

Regardless of build tool, I have seen people doing a clean task/phase before every time they do package/compile or ... is it really necessary? 
Dose build tools use reuse artifacts of previous builds?

Comment: The answer to that question is that "it depends". Generally people do a clean action before a build to ensure there is nothing present from the last build that might influence this build. For example I may not want to create a jar file where 90% of the class files were previously built.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you see `clean install` as the default command, but I would encourage everybody to use `verify` instead.

When executing `clean` the target-folder is removed which makes it impossible to do incremental builds. Plugins have enough information to detect if they should do their action. For instance: the maven-compiler-plugin compares the java sourcesfiles and the compiled classfiles (and other things) to see if files needs to be (re)compiled. If you think that a plugin is not working correctly with incremental builds, please file an issue for that plugin.

The `install` was often required with multimodules in Maven2, but Maven3 is capable to resolve these inner module dependency references. The only thing 'install' does is copying artifacts to the local repository (=IO=expensive). And it'll make your local repo look different compared to your coworkers, which might give different results during builds. Better to let a buildserver push those artifacts to the shared remote repositories and let every pull those SNAPSHOTs from there. Only in rare cases calling install is valid (experienced Maven users know when :) ), so instead please use `verify`.